# Secrets of Twitter and Foursquare Ajax-like

Tags: ajax, twitter, foursquare

Does anyone know how to make things like these:
Im talking about theses "hidden ajax" on Twitter home (Top tweets) and Foursquare Home (Recent Activity), that is in constant update, but theres no request under tools line Firebug.

Seems to be "hidden ajax". Does this exist?

[check it out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN9Xm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the requests on twitter it's using [jsonp](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) not ajax.